# PHP Trying to get property of non-object error in function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Need some help please. I am getting a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error in a function call that looks at an array.

The array I am calling is

```
$var = array(
    "variableA" => "abc123",
    "variableB" => "123456789"
);
```

The function I am using is

```
  public function getJson($var)
    {
 $resource = sprintf("/info/%s/%s/json", $var->variableA, $var->variableB);
        return $this->_restCall('GET', $resource);
     }
```

I cant understand why the array values are not being passed through?

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$var` is an *array* not an object. So you need to use array syntax, not object syntax:

```
public function getJson($var)
{
    $resource = sprintf("/info/%s/%s/json", $var['variableA'], $var['variableB']);
    return $this->_restCall('GET', $resource);
 }
```

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you so much. saved my sanity